# Xpath/HtmlAgilityPack: Getting the specific attributes from href tag

Tags: xpath, tags, html-parsing, href, html-agility-pack

I'm using the HtmlAgilityPack to parse href tags in an html file. The href tags look like this:

```
<h3 class="product-name"><a href="http://www.somewebsite.com/blahblah" title="Click Here to View This Product">Super Cool Product</a></h3>
```

So far I can successfully pull out the url and the title together, and display it in a list. This is the main code I'm using to parse the html:

```
var linksOnPage = from lnks in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h3[@class='product-name']//a")
                        where
                            lnks.Attributes["href"] != null && 
                            lnks.InnerText.Trim().Length > 0
                      select new
                      {
                          Url = lnks.Attributes["href"].Value,
                          Text = lnks.InnerText
                      };
```

The code above gives me a result that looks like this:

```
Super Cool Product - http://www.somewebsite.com/blahblah
```

I'm trying to figure out how to pull out the name and url separately, and put them into separate strings, instead of pulling them out together and putting them into one string. I'm guessing there is some sort of Xpath notation I can use to do this. I would be extremely thankful if someone could lead me in the right direction

Thanks,
Miles

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are looking for? From what you describe, it seems you already have that.

Comment: I'm trying to get the anchor text by itself. Right now, my code returns the anchor text and the url and counts that as one string.

Comment: Haha nevermind I figured it out. I took this from an example and forgot to delete the line "Text = lnks.InnerText". Sorry for wasting anyone's time.